# Cannot use DB driver when queue

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

My mySQL and MongoDB are working fine when it's in normal controller, How ever,
When I'm queue some job to access the DB, the Error shows up,
Even I use the namespace of the db driver.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\model\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;


class ProductOrderTimer implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

     public $orderId;
     public $orderLife;

     public function __construct($orderId,$orderLife)
     {
         $this->orderId = $orderId;
         $this->orderLife = $orderLife;
     }


    public function handle()
    {

      $test = Product::all();
    //...other code

}
```

the Error message:

```
[2018-10-17 18:10:39] local.ERROR: PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40
```

if I access the mongoDB , the error log would log this:

```
[2018-10-17 13:37:48] local.ERROR: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://mongo:tcp://172.17.0.4:27017'. Invalid host string in URI. in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:83
```

these DB works fine , And Job works fine without DB access. But when they put together, the DB will fail.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have drivers for pdo installed you need these in order to create a pdo connection

Take a look at the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php